# How do I properly format this json object in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I need to be able to create a data structure in PHP which creates for instance, an array of car vendors. Each of those array elements contains a child array which holds types of cars for that vendor.

So you'd have something like

```
$cars['toyota'] = array("camry", "etc");
```

I need to be able to create this data structure in PHP so that on the JavaScript side of things I can do something like

```
alert(cars.vendor[0].type[1])
```

How do I encode that data structure on the PHP end of things?

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP >5.2.0, try [`json_encode($cars)`](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

This will make an array in an array, but it won't give you what you have in your javascript sample:

```
$vendors = array(
  'toyota' => array('camry', 'etc.'),
  'honda' => array('civic', 'fit', 'etc.'),
);
```

You probably don't need all the embedded levels of `vendors[0].types[1]` to get your information organized.

Comment: My question is how does the array have to look in PHP before json_encode spits out the format I want it in? an array of arrays is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to set it up to do it how you want:

```
<script>
    var test = <?php
        print json_encode(array('vendor' => array(
            'toyota' => array('type' => array('camry','siena')),
            'mitsubishi' => array('type' => array('mirage','galant'))
        )));
    ?>;
    alert(test.vendor['toyota'].type[1]); // siena
    alert(test.vendor['mitsubishi'].type[0]); // mirage
</script>
```

I would recommend skipping the vendor and type part of it altogether unless you're holding other stuff in that object too, and doing something like this:

```
<script>
    var vendors = <?php
        print json_encode(array(
            'toyota' => array('camry','siena'),
            'mitsubishi' => array('mirage','galant')
        ));
    ?>;
    alert(vendors['toyota'][1]); // siena
    alert(vendors['mitsubishi'][0]); // mirage
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array();
$data['userDetails'] =array( array("username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
$data["wsfunction"]="user_authentication";
```

then output of json encode function as follows

```
{"userDetails":[{"username":"Username","password":"Password"}],"wsfunction":"user_authentication"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey, associative arrays and objects are being treat equally in Javascript. Thus, PHP structure

```
$cars['toyota'] = array("camry", "etc");
```

would be equivalent to this in JSON:

```
var cars = { "toyota": [ "camry", "etc" ] };
```

You can easily convert PHP structure to JSON one with [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function.
See [json.org](http://json.org) for JSON format details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cars = array();
$cars['toyota'] = array("camry", "etc");
$json = json_encode($cars);
```

will give you a javascript struct of

```
var cars = {
    toyota: [ 'camry', 'etc' ]
};
```

If you want

```
var cars = {
    vendor: [ { type: [ 'camry', 'etc' ] } ]
}
```

which will allow you to call `alert(cars.vendor[0].type[1])` the PHP array should look like

```
$cars = array(
    'vendor' => array(
        array('type' => array("camry", "etc"))
    )
);
$json = json_encode($cars);
```

But as having been pointed out [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640870/how-do-i-properly-format-this-json-object-in-php/640896#640896) you should perhaps skip the `vendor`-part and use the apprpriate vendor-name as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
class EmptyObject {}
$cars = new EmptyObject();
$cars->vendor[] = array('type' => array('camry','sienna'));
$cars->vendor[] = array('type' => array('mirage','galant'));
$json = json_encode($cars);
print $json;
// this produces:
// {"vendor":[{"type":["camry","sienna"]},{"type":["mirage","galant"]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using PHP 5 you can use the function [json_encode](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), as many have already answered.

If noy, if you're using PHP 4, you'll need [something extra like this](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/71).